# Is there a keyboard shortcut for copying a line from left to right in VSCode compareEditor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I am looking for a keyboard shortcut that performs the same action as clicking the arrow next to the right line of a diff, when comparing two files in VSCode (compareEditor not VCS). The action copies the highlighted lines from the left file to the right file.

[image: Screenshot of VSCode]

Note: I am aware of `workbench.action.compareEditor.focusOtherSide`, but this is not what I am looking for.

Comment: in the keyboard shortcuts search for `compareEditor` and see if there is a command that might do what you want, in v1.70 I haven't found one, if no keybinding yet you can create one